# Backward compatibility of Storyboards from Xcode 6 to Xcode 5 + Support iOS 7 in Xcode 6

Tags: xcode, storyboard, xcode5, xcode6, xcode-storyboard

After making some changes in my project under **Xcode 6**, I can't open `storyboard` file (and build project) from **Xcode 5.**

Since there is no way to Distribute apps to AppStore from Xcode 6, while it under beta - I have to build application under Xcode 5.

Is any way to make storyboard backward compatibile with **Xcode 5**?
I found in the header of storyboard file this string:

```
<capability name="Constraints with attributes relative to the layout margin" minToolsVersion="6.0"/>
```

I suppose, that it's need to delete or edit some new keys, that new Xcode 6 uses, but can't detect which one.

(Revert commit is VERY unlikely, because there is a LOT of changes.)

[image]

---

## UPD:

There is another problem, that appears in Xcode 6 - it adds baseline constraints, that not available in **iOS 7**, and it cause crashes on it. (Xcode even not always highlight this warnings!) - to fix it refer to my answer, how to remove `baseline` attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hooray! I fix it! Hope It will be useful for others:

I use regex to find all dummy strings *(regex version that support **Sublime 2**)*

1. Open your stroyboard file in favorite text editor.
2. find all using regex `(\w)Margin"`
3. Replace all occurrences by pattern: `\1"`
4. remove `<capability name="Constraints with attributes relative to the layout margin" minToolsVersion="6.0"/>` from beggining of file.
5. Find and remove from storyboard file all strings by pattern: `.*"baseline".*\n`
6. To fix misaligns: Open file in Xcode 5 - and Update constraints for all views.
7. That's it! **Profit!**

---

**UPD:**
I found that "baseline" constraints causes crashes also, but Xcode doesn't show any warnings about these constrains!

To fix it - remove from storyboard file all strings by pattern: `.*"baseline".*\n`

Comment: Great Solution! Wish i could give you +10 instead of +1!

Comment: @S1LENTWARRIOR Thanks, also, there is possible another conflict with `baseline` attributes, that also not available in iOS 7, but Xcode some time automatically add it! I will update answer soon!

Answer (score 1):

Open your storyboard in editor. Right click> open in editor. Copy your ui xml leaving out the header where you would find the version and storyboard id.

Next, paste your xml content to your xcode 5 storyboard file.

Comment: It's not about version digit. It use different keys, that xcode 5 don't know. So, you try to do this you obviously get a crash!